# Error Theme.AppCompat en Xamarin Android

Tags: android-drawerlayout, xamarin.android

Me sale el siguiente error al querer ejecutar una App Android Xamarin

You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

éste es mi archivo manifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="KobitAndroidBeta.KobitAndroidBeta" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <application android:label="KobitAndroidBeta"></application>
</manifest>
```

Y este mi archivo de style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu activity, agrega:

```
[Activity(Label = "DrawerMenu", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Base")]
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía que también tenía que indicarle al activity iniciar el tema, en un momento marco tu respuesta como aceptada ;)

Comment: Así es, cada vez que inicias un activity, debes indicarle el tema que usar, puede ser uno propio que defines en el style.xml o uno ya hecho. Saludos!